# openpyxl: to create chart using discrete columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to python and trying to make chart from certain sheet using the openpyxl module.
What I'm trying to do is to basically make double axis chart from a sheet.

the problem is that when setting the range for data, I want to exclude some columns so I can later make second chart and combine the charts to get secondary axis per: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/secondary.html?highlight=secondary%20axis

I can't switch the order of columns because it's a fixed form.

Would there be any way of doing this ? I've searched a lot but there seems to be no explanation.

For example:
if I have ws as below,

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 | Cell 7 | Cell 8 |

For chart 1:

I want column 'A' as'category'
and designate column 'B' & 'D' as data, excluding 'C' in between.

For chart 2:

I want column 'A' as'category'
and designate column 'C' as data

and add those 2 charts to make double axis chart ( 1st y axis for 'B'&'D' / 2nd y axis for 'C' )

I tried to make the chart using the excel, and then copy the data selected to use 'range_string=' but didn't work.

this is the code I got, It makes 1 chart consisting all data, not divided.
I just  don't know where to go further from this...

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference

wb = load_workbook(address for excel file)
ws = wb['sheet name']

l_chart = LineChart()
l_data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row= 1, max_col= ws.max_column, max_row= ws.max_row)
l_cat = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row= 1, max_row= ws.max_row)

l_chart.add_data(l_data, titles_from_data= True)
l_chart.set_categories(l_cat)

ws.add_chart(l_chart, 'M1')
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Also you can just copy all this data into a new file.

Comment: I really couldnt even try but make 1 chart consisting all the data.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your post. I'd have done it, had there not been too many pending edits XD. Also, what you ask for seems doable, but I won't do more than guide you, that's why I need to see your code.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to here too haha
I've edited the post and it seems better now i guess

Comment: you'll have to give me a sec while i download python

Comment: I find your specifications for the chart confusing. Can you do what you request manually in Excel? If so post a screenshot?